# Google Elevation API with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, jsonp, google-elevation-api

I am trying to use the Google Elevation API with the getJSON function of JQuery.

I am using this code which is using JSONP :

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=23.444,45.4545&sensor=false&jsoncallback=?", function(json){
    alert("a");
});
```

I can see in Firebug that the GET request is correctly send and I receive the correct response from Google :

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "location": {
      "lat": 23.4440000,
      "lng": 45.4545000
    },
    "elevation": 816.7996216
  } ]
}
```

However I never the Alert and I get this error from Firebug :

```
invalid label
"status": "OK",\n
```

I am using the Google Maps API v2 so I connato use the build in method.

Is there any way to get the elevation with the Google Elevation API via an AJAX request and without creating a proxy?

Thanks for your help.

Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google elevation API don't support JSONP (Thanks to Nick Craver for the explanation) and I cannot use the ElevationService which is only available for the v3 Google Maps API.

So I decided to use an other webservice to get the elevation :

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#astergdem

example : http://ws.geonames.org/astergdemJSON?lat=X&lng=Y&callback=?

This webservice support JSONP, so it can be use easily with JQuery and the getJSON method.

Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

That API doesn't support JSONP, it's returning JSON only...so yes you'll need to proxy in this case.

To be clear, the *correct* response would be like this:

```
someFunction({
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "location": {
      "lat": 23.4440000,
      "lng": 45.4545000
    },
    "elevation": 816.7996216
  } ]
})
```

jQuery replaces `callback=?` with `callback=someFunction`, but google doesn't use this parameter since this service doesn't support JSONP...so the problem is you're *effectively* doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "location": {
      "lat": 23.4440000,
      "lng": 45.4545000
    },
    "elevation": 816.7996216
  } ]
}
</script>
```

Which results in an error, as that's not valid JavaScript...you get an invalid label error.  If it had the function wrapper there, it *would* be valid and it'd execute that function jQuery made (from your `success` callback).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the G̶e̶o̶L̶o̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ElevationService class from the JavaScript API. There's no need to proxy.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#ElevationService

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Use the ElevationService instead: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#ElevationService

Comment: I cannot use the elevation service because it is only available on the API v3 and as I said in my question I am using the v2 API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris Broadfoot said, there's a special class for that in API v3
A better example here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation
You don't need to deal with JSONP nor another service.